# Update a field to increment until another field changes

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

This is my first stack-overflow question so apologies if I do something wrong. I avoided using the term "index" in the question so as not to confuse my question with database indices. This question is about index notation - to specify the position of an element in a series of items.

---

#### Summary

I have a system which stores `documents` with their corresponding `paragraphs`; each `document` contains many `paragraphs`. This data is stored in a MySQL database.

The `paragraphs` table has the following fields:

- Primary key (AUTO INCREMENT)
- Document id (foreign key to the document table)

I wish to add a new field to the `paragraphs` table set to the index of the given paragraph with respect to the document that it's in. This query will only run once during the migration of adding this field; then I plan to populate it as the paragraphs are inserted.

The first paragraph in each document should have index = 0. The second paragraph in each document should have index = 1.

#### Paragraphs table

> Primary key: 1
> Document id: 1
> Index: 0
>
> Primary key: 2
> Document id: 1
> Index: 1
>
> Primary key: 3
> Document id: 1
> Index: 2
>
> Primary key: 4
> Document id: 2
> Index: 0
>
> Primary key: 5
> Document id: 2
> Index: 1

An obvious way to do this is to do it on a per-document basis, but this seems to be inefficient across a large database of documents.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Wow, great question Dom - I'd be really intrigued to see what the answer is. Oh, and welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using variables (after adding the column, of course):

```
alter table paragraphs add index int;

set @d := 0;
set @i := 0;

update paragraphs
    set index = (if(@d = document_id, @i := @i + 1,
                    if(@d := document_id, @i := 1, @i := 1)
                   )
                ) - 1  -- to start numbering at 0 rather than 1
    order by document_id, primary_key;
```

Note:  `index` is a really bad name for a column, because it is a SQL keyword.  Name the column something else, such as `paragraph_number`.

Comment: ...and primary key is a bad name.

Comment: @Gordon The question asked for the first paragraph to be zero - I don't quite see how that is done.  I'm probably missing something, if you could elaborate, that would be most appreciated.

Comment: Thank you - this is perfect.